# Python Xlrd to import .xslx Template, the use Openpyxl to Edit and Re-save .xslx File

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd, shutil

I have an .xslx file with specific formatting and objects that I am using for reports that I plan on producing on a large scale using Python. I originally was openpyxl to load a copy of the template (openpyxl.load_workbook()), write a Pandas dataframe to the file (openpyxl.dataframe_to_rows()), then save the file for future distribution. I found out that openpyxl.load_workbook does not load the formatting or objects so they are removed from the new file. So then tried xlrd to open the file (xlrd.open_workbook()) which loaded the formatting and objects properly. However openpyxl will no longer write to the file creating empty copies of the template file. Is there another package I can use that will handle the reading/writing by itself or a package I can use instead of openpyxl? Xlsxwriter didn't work either. See code sample below.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import pandas as pd
import shutil

shutil.copy2('template.xlsx', 'new_report.xlsx')
book = open_workbook('new_report.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(book, engine='openpyxl')
ws = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    for r in dataframe_to_rows(result, index=False, header=False):
        ws.cell(colx=1, rowx=1)
        ws.append(r)
book.save('new_report.xlsx')
```

I'm also getting the errors: "AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'save'" and "AttributeError: 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'append'" from the code if anyone has suggestions for those problems.

Comment: Pandas uses xlrd internally when reading Excel files but all formatting will be lost anyway because dataframes don't have any formatting.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote but xlrd will keep all formatting and objects from an existing Excel file. I just needed to find a way to add content to the file without overwriting any existing formatting or objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using formulas to recreate any formatting I had in the existing Excel file after pasting the new data. I'm still missing the objects (Ex. shapes) but my reports will live without them until I can find another work around.